# Trouble getting PHP to execute Lua script

Tags: php, bash, lua, environment-variables, torch

So I'm working with PHP to attempt to execute a script I have in the same directory. The script runs fine locally and the permissions for the http-data user are set to be able to execute the script referenced in this block of PHP

```
$cmd = system('th neural_style.lua -style_image'.' ~/'.$style.'.jpg '.'-content_image '.$content_image.' -gpu 0 -backend cudnn -save_iter 1 -cudnn_autotune -output_image /var/www/html/processed/'.$email.'/out.png 2>&1', $retval);
echo '
</pre>
<hr />Recent output: ' . $last_line . '
<hr />Return value: ' . $retval;
```

The script should execute fine using the system method from what I understand, I know the variables look messy though this is the error I get from PHP:

> sh: th: command not found

I set my default interpreter to bash instead of dash thinking that might be an issue, no dice. Torch is in the same directory, and like I said runs fine as my login.

I know what I'm trying to do in a way is like sacrilege, if there is a better way to run a script that takes 8 minutes roughly to complete using some user input from the web, I want to know. This is just what came natural to me. I'm looking to notify the user when the process is complete with an email anyways so any way of executing it is just dandy.

Edit: any mention of "http-data" was supposed to say "www-data".

Answer (score 0):

Change the default shell for your `http-data` user to `bash` or `dash`. It is currently using `sh`.

Check what your `$PATH` variable is inside the PHP environment.

Comment: I changed default to bash for http-data and restarted.

Checked my $PATH for Torch and tried one where it was inside of the `/var/www/html/torch` and then the original spot `/home/username/torch/install/bin/`, did source ~/.bashrc and neither worked. Restarted apache2 also so that's not it.

Comment: @DylanMoore If the error is still the same, then do `system('echo $PATH');` in php.

Comment: `/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin`

How do I get it to understand the other paths? Looked it up before asking, no links at first glance.